# Is there anything wrong with getting a callback from AsyncTask in this way?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am going to end up with several classes that each perform a different `AsyncTask` and a single '**manager**' class that will be responsible for starting these tasks and handling the result.

Is there any problem with using an interface to provide a callback to the same object from multiple instances of `AsyncTask` in this way?

### A typical task class example:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class SomeBackgroundAction extends AsyncTask<SomeObject, Void, Boolean> {

    public interface SomeBackgroundActionDelegate {
        void result(Boolean result);
    }

    private SomeBackgroundActionDelegate delegate;

    public SomeBackgroundAction(SomeBackgroundActionDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(SomeObject... theseThings) {
        // some more code
        return theseThings[0].doThingThatReturnsBoolean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if (delegate != null) {
            delegate.result(aBoolean);
        }
    }
}
```

and starting the tasks as such:

```
new SomeBackgroundAction((r) -> {
            if (r) {
                // do good
            } else {
                // do bad :(
            }

        }).execute(someObject);
```

Is this good practice or is there a better pattern I should be looking at to do this?

Comment: It is perfectly fine

Comment: I just had it in my head that if two tasks finish at the same time then it might cause problems but I suppose onPostExecute() is on the main thread already and dished out by the handler.